# Batching in DirectX

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I have done a framework so far in DirectX 9 and It uses a Single VertexBuffer which draws every texture I load, I have used one Vertex Array which draws every single Texture Quad inside of a Lock and Unlock call. I have heard there is a thing called Batching where I can Lock it once and Unlock when I draw everything. I know I can draw every texture quad in one call to lock and unlock but I have no idea how i can set different textures to each of these. Can Anyone here Guide me ?

```
vertexBufferRHW->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&VerticesRHW, NULL);

VerticesRHW[0].Color = color;
VerticesRHW[0].X = (float) Position.X;
VerticesRHW[0].Y = (float) Position.Y;
VerticesRHW[0].Z = 0.0f;
VerticesRHW[0].RHW = 1.0f;
VerticesRHW[0].U = 0.0f;
VerticesRHW[0].V = 0.0f;

VerticesRHW[1].Color = color;
VerticesRHW[1].X = (float) (Position.X+TextureFile.Width);
VerticesRHW[1].Y = (float) Position.Y;
VerticesRHW[1].Z = 0.0f;
VerticesRHW[1].RHW = 1.0f;
VerticesRHW[1].U = 1.0f;
VerticesRHW[1].V = 0.0f;

VerticesRHW[2].Color = color;
VerticesRHW[2].X = (float) (Position.X+TextureFile.Width);
VerticesRHW[2].Y = (float) (Position.Y+TextureFile.Height);
VerticesRHW[2].Z = 0.0f;
VerticesRHW[2].RHW = 1.0f;
VerticesRHW[2].U = 1.0f;
VerticesRHW[2].V = 1.0f;

VerticesRHW[3].Color = color;
VerticesRHW[3].X = (float) Position.X ;
VerticesRHW[3].Y = (float) (Position.Y+TextureFile.Height);
VerticesRHW[3].Z = 0.0f;
VerticesRHW[3].RHW = 1.0f;
VerticesRHW[3].U = 0.0f;
VerticesRHW[3].V = 1.0f;

vertexBufferRHW->Unlock();

spriteDevice->SetTexture(0,TextureFile.TextureFile);
spriteDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN,0,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make all your quads a height/width of 1 and then do a for loop like so:

```
for( ... loop through all the textures )
{
    // create a matrix that scales your quad to make it the correct width/height and in the correct location
    D3DXMATRIX matrix, scale, translation;
    D3DXMatrixScaling( &scale, texture.width, texture.height, 0 );
    D3DXMatrixTranslation( &translation, position.x, position.y, 0 );
    matrix = scale * translation;
    spriteDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_WORLDMATRIX, &matrix ); 
    spriteDevice->SetTexture(0,texture);
    spriteDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN,0,2);
}
```

Comment: but in the case when I use Transformed vertices ?

Comment: you'll have to populate some data structure with your transformations...ie have an array of D3DXVECTORs that contain the position of each quad, and then use the vectors to create the D3DXMatrixTranslation (assuming this is what your asking?).

Comment: NO that is not wat i meant i was telling that if I use Transformed Vertices (D3DFVF_XYZRHW) So I cant use translation and Scale when I use this vertex format